# How to identify if a checkbox was checked through a mouse or keyboard?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, keyboard, mouse

I know it's a weird question, but is possible to determinate (using PHP/JavaScrip) the device's source of the 'check action'? I need to find out when a user click on a checkbox option, which device he/she used to do the actual click.

I hope I made sense here.

Comment: Well you're not going to be able to do it with PHP considering your PHP code doesn't run in the browser... In JavaScript I guess you could trap the click, mouseup and keyup events and figure out whether mouseup or keyup was most recent. You won't be able to tell the difference between a mouse and a trackball. I'm curious why you care?

Comment: Sorry for this misunderstanding. You are right about PHP, it was me thinking too ahead on the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Javascript, this is easy.  You can attach click and keydown events to the checkbox (`onclick`, `onkeydown`, or use jQuery if you want) and they will be triggered on click or keydown.  By "click" with the keyboard I assume you mean highlighting the checkbox via tabbing and pressing space.  This will still trigger the keydown event, but not the click.

Comment: Yes, you are about the keybaord.

Comment: (Why is this getting upvoted?) This is _wrong_. Pressing space on a checkbox triggers the click event.

Comment: @nnnnnn space triggers `click`, yes, but mouse click does not trigger `keydown` and `keydown` has precedence.  Just stop the event propagation in `keydown`.

Comment: That's contrary to what your answer said, and won't work anyway. Stopping propagation stops the keydown event bubbling up, it doesn't stop the click. `event.preventDefault()` will (or should) stop the click event, but it also stops the checkbox from changing. (So the full solution would include handling the keydown event to cancel the default behaviour and programmatically toggle the checkbox.)

Comment: @nnnnnn  not necessarily.  You could just record that `keydown` was reached.  You could still record that `click` was reached too, but just have `keydown` take priority.

Comment: Could you give us an example?